# Тех или тем, как правильно?

Tags: управление

Мы возносим молитвы и воздаем дань памяти ТЕХ наших соотечественников, братьев, союзников, кто пролил свою кровь,
Тех или тем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос ставится от слова *дань:* воздаём дань кому? нашим соотечественник**ам**... А не *память (кого?).*

Comment: Вопрос-то, естественно, от глагола, потому что "соотечественникам" - это косвенное дополнение: воздаём (что?) дань (кому?) тем...

Comment: @homocomputeris: вы же сами пишете после "дани" вопрос "кому?".

Comment: Смотрите фокус: воздать (кому?) им (что?) дань, воздать (кому?) им. От слова "дань" ничего не зависит.

Comment: От "дани" с тем же успехом можно задать этот вопрос.

Comment: Ещё можно задать грамматически верный вопрос "дань (чья?) тех", откуда и получится предложение в вопросе. Чтобы это проверить, можно пойти от обратного, заменив глагол на антоним: "заберём (что?) дань (у кого?) у тех". Если б падеж зависел от "дани", то ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Выдумщик вы. Прям не изменилось бы! Ещё как меняется.

Comment: Повторюсь, что это называется слабым глагольным управлением, и описано в § 1748, раздел "Подчинительные связи глагола" "Русской грамматики".

Answer (score 0):

Управление такое же, как у глагола *дать*:

> Воздать *кому?* тем нашим соотечественникам.